# How can I create a browser router in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm finding it difficult to create a Browser Route in React. Here is what I want to do:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import RecipeList from './containers/recipe-list/RecipeList';
import Recipe from './containers/recipe-details/RecipeDetails';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import Error from './components/error/Error';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={RecipeList} />
          <Route path="./containers/recipe-details/RecipeDetails" component={Recipe} />
          <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}


import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Recipe() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="../../containers/recipe-details/RecipeDetails">Recipe</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem comes in my `Recipe` component which I want to create a separate route for.
Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the `Route` is the link in the browser that will show up that component and not the path to the component in your directory structure, you can set up your `Route` and `Link` like below

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={RecipeList} />
          <Route path="/recipe" component={Recipe} />
          <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Recipe() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/recipe">Recipe</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up, bro! You got it. Though I had to move the ```<BrowserRoute>``` to wrap everything in the ```return``` statement in the ```App``` component. If not I got this Error: ```Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>```. Can you suggest why?

Comment: Additionally, my ```RecipeDetails``` will have a dynamic parameter such as ```id```. So how can I cater for this in the route? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @SundayEzeilo you can use params with Routes like `<Route path="/recipe/:id" component={Recipe} />` and the link will then be `<Link to="/recipe/1">Recipe</Link>` or similar

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, all, for your quick and positive replies. Happy coding!

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Your Route path will match what you'd like your url to look like

- `<Route exact path="/" component={RecipeList} />` will open your RecipeList component with this website: [www.yourwebsite.com/](http://www.yourwebsite.com/)
- `<Route path="/recipe" component={Recipe} />` will open your Recipe component with this website: [www.yourwebsite.com/recipe](http://www.yourwebsite.com/recipe)

I don't know exactly how you'd like it, but I'd imagine you want a more simple path like:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={RecipeList} />
     <Route path="/RecipeDetails" component={Recipe} />
     <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>
```

and accessing your route through a link is as simple as:

```
<Link to="/RecipeDetails">Recipe</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Additionally, my ```RecipeDetails``` will have a dynamic parameter such as ```id```. So how can I cater for this in the route? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: <Route path="/RecipeDetails/:id" component={Recipe} /> and to use it, import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom' and to get the value back let { id } = useParams();

Comment: this documentation might help you out in your next steps https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks